# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/unstable-native-dependencies'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-dom

I am writing applications with React Native. I am using Expo.

My React and react-dom versions are 17.0.0 but I get an error like this on the expo web page. How can I solve the problem?

"react": "17.0.0",
"react-dom": "17.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",

It is showing as follow:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at package.json, there's react-dom or not

Comment: There is react-dom.

I have now downgraded the version to 16.8.0. The warning in Console is like the image.

http://prnt.sc/wjquws

Answer (score 0):

According to your console warning, instead of

```
'componentWillMount'
```

you should give

```
'componentDidMount'
```